# subfolder wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a ubuntu server that has a wordpress installed on with link "https://gditac.com"

after that I installed another wordpress on subfolder like "https://gditac.com/news" but the problem is the second website redirects on first and show 404 not found page. I searche a lot but couldn't solve my problem.

here the htaccess for the root website  :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and here the htaccess for subfolder website  :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to create a subdomain e.g. news.gditac.com, install there your wordpress and make a permanent redirect from https://gditac.com/news to https://news.gditac.com

If you really want to install it on a subfolder then read this article:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134839/is-it-possible-to-install-wordpress-within-wordpress-installation

Alex

Comment: thanks for responding.I try all the ways but its not going to be fixed. maybe its related to the SSL or some thing. I tested the above htaccess on other website and it was fine.